# Tried to install Nvidia drivers, now I can only boot to tty

Tags: command-line, fedora, nvidia, display-settings

I'm on Fedora 23.

I followed [this guide](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/) and got all the way up to the "2.7 Reboot to runlevel 3" step. I did that step then rebooted and now I can only boot into tty.

I tried to continue on with the installation so I did the remaining steps on tty and then I rebooted again thinking the display would work now since I installed Nvidia drivers.

Well it doesn't. Still goes to tty. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Boot into single-user-mode by pressing esc upon startup, then after a little while, press any key, and select single-user-mode, then try these commands

```
mv /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r) nouveau.img;
dracut /boot/initramfs-$(uname -r).img $(uname -r)
```

Then reboot.

Note: You may have to try different commands to uninstall nVidia Drivers in 
single-user-mode. You might also wan't to try text-only-mode, and different systems have different ways of going to single-user-mode/text-only-mode. If pressing ESC upon startup doesn't work, try pressing e or a.